# Configuration of mod_authnz_ldap to work with Active Directory

Tags: authentication, active-directory, apache-http-server

Please help to find a good tutorial / step by step instructions how to configure mod_authnz_ldap to work with Active Directory (I use Apache 2.2).
Apache provides good documentation, but I want to find better one:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html